# CSS Way of saying and

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a sort of pure html/css tabs system. I have

```
<div>
    <input class="tab1" type="radio" checked/>
    <input class="tab2" type="radio"/>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="tab-1">

    </div>
    <div class="tab-2">

    </div>
</div>
```

And my css

```
.content > div {
    opacity:0;
}

input.tab1:checked ~ .tab-1, input.tab2:checked ~ .tab-2  {
    opacity: 1
}
```

However the tilde `~` isnt working as its supposed to (because the divs aren't exactly a sibling) - How can I get the css to sort of work across to other nodes? Is there a way of 'saying' and in css?

Comment: with `CSS` all what you are able to do is changing apperance, nothing else.

Comment: You have to change the HTML structure in order to achieve what you want with pure CSS. Also keep in mind that you are setting the opacity of `.content` to `0`; no matter what `opacity` you set to its children, they'll always be invisible.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo ive edited it now

Comment: @Sajmon Yep, tabs are about appearance (`display: none` and `block`). And `:target` is being abused out there for mimicking JS effects like http://ie7nomore.com/fun/responsive-menu/menu2.html#navigation (works when width<640px). Alas, the (poor or uncommon) accessibility of these nice demos makes me in favor of JS solutions (and fallbacks as much as possible). But in theory and in demos, you can do a lot with CSS3.

Comment: @FelipeAlsacreations you right but i should look at CSS3 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to go up one level and you cannot do that in CSS as there is no parent selector in CSS. You might want to read this article: [why we don't have a parent selector in CSS](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) (there will be a parent selector in [CSS4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/), however)

What you can do:

**Option 1**: change your HTML:

*.a*

```
<input class="tab1" type="radio" checked/>
<input class="tab2" type="radio"/>

<div class="content">
    <div class="tab-1"></div>
    <div class="tab-2"></div>
</div>
```

and use `input.tab1:checked ~ .content .tab-1`

*.b* Try a structure like described here: http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/ - basically, the idea is that you don't make a group of tabs and a group of tab contents, but you group each tab with its corresponding content.

**Option 2**: use JavaScript (which goes against the idea of a pure CSS tab system, it's true)

---

**Important note**: keep in mind that setting `opacity` < 0 on a parent node makes all the children have the same `opacity` value and *there is nothing you can do to change that* (except setting the opacity of the parent to 1 again :P ).

Comment: Thanks i've fixed the opacity now. I've managed to get it to work thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a `,` instead of a `~`.

Check out the list of all CSS Selectors:

[W3 CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)

Comment: This wouldn't work because it would select the `.tab-1` even if the `tab-2` radio is checked

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with pure CSS. There is no relation between `tab1` and `tab-1`.

I believe this is taken from jQuery tabs markup? You are probably better off sticking to using jQuery tabs than trying to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you cannot, as there is no CSS way to travel up the hierarchy. You will have to do this with Javascript.